# What to do with a linear regression model with non-normal residuals and evidence of seasonality?

Tags: regression, residuals

Assuming I already have an existing linear regression model: $y(t) = a + bx(t) + e(t)$,

where:

- $a$ & $b$ are the constant coefficients
- $e$ is the model residual error
- $t$ denotes time

You've noticed that:

- There are trends in residuals and as a result the assumption of normality with constant variance is violated.
- There is  "seasonality" in the model residuals showing repeating  pattern in  prediction  errors  over time (e.g. follows an annual cycle).

**Question:** How do we improve or adjust the model but without changing the constant coefficients?

This is only a hypothetical question. I am only looking for the approach that can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of the seasonal cycle in your residuals, you can fit an ARIMA model to the residuals, yielding a so-called [regression with ARIMA errors](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). This will work only on residuals and leave your regression coefficient estimates for $a$ and $b$ as they are.

In R, you can do this using `auto.arima` in the `forecast` package. Feed your regressors into the `xreg` parameter.